# Making a function in a app that changes fields in another app

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Hi Djangonauts,
                 I am new to Django so please forgive any errors in logic or code
I have a accounts app that has a Profile model with a field `is_verified` Now I have another app called verification. That has a model Verification and a field called `verify` I want to create a logic such that when you verify the user on the verification app. The `is_verified` on profile app is also marked as True

**models.py for Profile**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**models.py for Verification**

```
class Verification(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='verified')
    applied_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    verify = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    deny = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    verified_on = models.DateTimeField()
    denied_on = models.DateTimeField()

    def verify_a_user(self, user):
        self.verify = True
        user.profile.is_verified = True
        return user.profile.is_verified.save()
```

Is this correct? Is there a better way to execute this code

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals/

Either send a pre_save or post_save signal from your Verification model. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save

Then register the listener function in your Profile app.

For details and example

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals/#connecting-to-signals-sent-by-specific-senders

Comment: I will definitely take a look at signals. but is there another way besides Django signals